# What is Two-Way Open Jaw?

Tags: international-travel

I know well what we mean by Origin Open Jaw, Turn Around Open Jaw, Double Open Jaw and One Way Open Jaw.
I want to know what we mean by Two-Way Open Jaw.

Comment: SYD->MEL->ADL, ADL->MEL->SYD (separate PNRs)?

Comment: suspect TWOJ==DOJ, but happy to be corrected as I'm unsure, so not writing an answer.

Comment: Turn Around Open Jaw Example: DEL - PAR - (surface) - NCE - DEL.  Double Open Jaw Example: DEL - PAR - (Surface) - NCE - BOM.  Origin Open Jaw Example: DEL - PAR - BOM.  One Way Open Jaw Example: DEL - NBO - MCT - PAR - (surface) - NCE - NYC.

Comment: Pretty sure its just the same as a double open jaw.

Comment: Never heard of "two way" in any ticketing parlance. The expression "two way" does not appear in the IATA Ticketing Handbook. I don't think this is any kind of official terminology.

Comment: The person that asked the question made the following comment on an answer that has since been deleted.  Re-posting here so that everyone can read it -  "I was asked a question like this in a job-interview. I still try to find out answer to this question. Of course, I know very well double open jaw. I even answered the Selection Committee that double open jaw is two-way open jaw. But, the One of the committee members remarked my answer wrong"

Answer (score 6):

Having checked with multiple travel agent staff, and multiple airline staff from multiple airlines, across multiple continents, not a single one of them had ever heard of this term.

Every one of them initially stated that was I was referring to was called a "Double Open Jaw", but once I stated that this was not what was being referred to (based on the OP's comments), they were at a loss to explain what it was.

Also, Google'ing for this term returns nothing interesting (except for this very question on StackExchange!) which would simply not be the case for such a term if it was a valid industry term (to give some context, "double open jaw" returns over 15,000 results)

Based on this I'd be very confident in stating that this is NOT a standard industry term.  I would suspect that one of two things is the case, either :

- This is a local term, used by the company you were interviewing for, but not used by the wider travel/airline community, or
- The interviewer was simply mistaken, either in their use of the term, or in stating that your answer was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is same term for double open jaw ticket. You go **A** -> **B**, returning **C** -> **D**.

Comment: ... where B and C are in the same general area (such that the airline recognize A-B, C-A and D-B, C-D as open-jaw itineraries), **and** A and D are in the same general area (such that A-B, B-D and A-C, C-D would also be open-jaw itineraries).